# P5.js Image Collision

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, p5.js

I recently figured out that image collisions in p5.js are quite different than regular rectangle collisions. If you want to keep aspect ratio of an image without setting manual height and width parameters in the `image()` function, then you can scale the image with the `scale()` function. This, however, does not change the area of the image, so to detect collisions, I have to multiply the image by the image scale that I set. For example, if set up in a constructor, to get the player width would be `playerImage.width * player.scale`.

So I've done all of this, and even made a function to show the area/hitbox of the image. Then, when I set this up with my collision function, the bottom and right sides detect the collisions fine, but the top and left sides seem to act quite strangely.

You can see what's going on here: https://image-colliding.stcollier.repl.co/

Does anyone know why the collision is off for the left and top edges?

Here is my code for the issue:

```js
let debug = true;

function preload() {

  playerImg = loadImage("https://image-colliding.stcollier.repl.co/Player.png")
  brickImg = loadImage("https://image-colliding.stcollier.repl.co/brick.jpeg")

}

function setup() {

  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight)

  player = new Player(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2, 0.5)
  brick = new Brick(windowWidth/10, windowHeight/3, 0.1)

  speed = 3;

}

function draw() {

  background(200, 200, 200)

  push();
  brick.display();
  pop();

  push();
  player.display();
  pop();

if (debug) {
  showRectCollider(player.x, player.y, playerImg.width * player.s, playerImg.height * player.s)

  showRectCollider(brick.x, brick.y, brickImg.width * brick.s, brickImg.height * brick.s)

  if (player.collidesImg(brick.x, brick.y, brickImg.width, brickImg.height, brick.s)) {
    collidingColor = 'green';
  } else {
    collidingColor = 'red'
  }
}

if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
  moveY(player, -speed)
}
if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
  moveY(player, speed)
}
if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
  moveX(player, -speed)
}
if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
  moveX(player, speed)
}

}

class Player {
  constructor(x, y, s) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.s = s;
  }
  display() {
    translate(this.x, this.y)
    scale(this.s)
    image(playerImg, 0, 0)
  }
  collidesFunc1(x, y, w, h) {
  if (
    this.x - w/2 <= x + w/2 &&
    this.x + w/2 >= x - w/2 && 
    this.y - h/2 <= y + h/2 && 
    this.y + h/2 >= y - h/2) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
    }
  }
  collidesFunc2(x, y, w, h) {
    if (
      this.x >= x - w &&
      this.x <= x + w &&
      this.y >= y - h &&
      this.y <= y + h) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  collidesImg(x, y, w, h, s) {
    if (
      this.x >= x - (w * s) &&
      this.x <= x + (w * s) &&
      this.y >= y - (h * s) &&
      this.y <= y + (h * s)) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

class Brick {
  constructor(x, y, s) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.s = s;
  }
  display() {
    translate(this.x, this.y)
    scale(this.s)
    image(brickImg, 0, 0)
  }
}

//Other functions

var collidingColor = 'red';

function showRectCollider(x, y, w, h) {
  noFill();
  stroke(collidingColor);
  strokeWeight(3);
  rect(x, y, w, h)
}

function moveX(object, speed) {
  object.x += speed;
}

function moveY(object, speed) {
  object.y += speed;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have three functions used for detecting collisions, and currently I'm using the `collidesImg()` function that I made. All three of the functions can be found on lines 71-106.

Thanks for any help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you have bbox centers (and you scale wrt to centers) then your collision detection is "is the h distance between the center points less than `(w1 + w2)/2` and is the v distance less than `(h1 + h2)/2`?". Don't use any of the corners, or edge coordinates, and things get a bit easier.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I think your're describing something like the collision function, as seen here (see code for expanded version):

  collidesFunc1(x, y, w, h) {
  if (
    this.x - w/2 <= x + w/2 &&
    this.x + w/2 >= x - w/2 && 
    this.y - h/2 <= y + h/2 && 
    this.y + h/2 >= y - h/2) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
    }
  }

I tried that, and that also doesn't work. Could you further clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collision logic was a bit off, here it is with explanatory comments:

```js
    collidesImg(x, y, w, h, s) {
        if (
            // right edge of player to the right of left edge of brick
            this.x + playerImg.width * this.s >= x &&
            // left edge of player to the left of right edge of brick
            this.x <= x + (w * s) &&
            // bottom edge of player below top edge of brick
            this.y + playerImg.height * this.s >= y &&
            // top edge of player above bottom edge of brick
            this.y <= y + (h * s)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```js
let debug = true;

function preload() {
    playerImg = loadImage("https://image-colliding.stcollier.repl.co/Player.png")
    brickImg = loadImage("https://image-colliding.stcollier.repl.co/brick.jpeg")
}

function setup() {

    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight)

    player = new Player(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, 0.5)
    brick = new Brick(windowWidth / 10, windowHeight / 3, 0.1)

    speed = 3;

}

function draw() {

    background(200, 200, 200)

    push();
    brick.display();
    pop();

    push();
    player.display();
    pop();

    if (debug) {
        if (player.collidesImg(brick.x, brick.y, brickImg.width, brickImg.height, brick.s)) {
            collidingColor = 'green';
        } else {
            collidingColor = 'red'
        }

        showRectCollider(player.x, player.y, playerImg.width * player.s, playerImg.height * player.s)
        showRectCollider(brick.x, brick.y, brickImg.width * brick.s, brickImg.height * brick.s)
    }

    if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
        moveY(player, -speed)
    }
    if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
        moveY(player, speed)
    }
    if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
        moveX(player, -speed)
    }
    if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
        moveX(player, speed)
    }

}

class Player {
    constructor(x, y, s) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.s = s;
    }
    display() {
        translate(this.x, this.y)
        scale(this.s)
        image(playerImg, 0, 0)
    }
    collidesFunc1(x, y, w, h) {
        if (
            this.x - w / 2 <= x + w / 2 &&
            this.x + w / 2 >= x - w / 2 &&
            this.y - h / 2 <= y + h / 2 &&
            this.y + h / 2 >= y - h / 2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    collidesFunc2(x, y, w, h) {
        if (
            this.x >= x - w &&
            this.x <= x + w &&
            this.y >= y - h &&
            this.y <= y + h) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    collidesImg(x, y, w, h, s) {
        if (
            // right edge of player to the right of left edge of brick
            this.x + playerImg.width * this.s >= x &&
            // left edge of player to the left of right edge of brick
            this.x <= x + (w * s) &&
            // bottom edge of player below top edge of brick
            this.y + playerImg.height * this.s >= y &&
            // top edge of player above bottom edge of brick
            this.y <= y + (h * s)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class Brick {
    constructor(x, y, s) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.s = s;
    }
    display() {
        translate(this.x, this.y)
        scale(this.s)
        image(brickImg, 0, 0)
    }
}

//Other functions

var collidingColor = 'red';

function showRectCollider(x, y, w, h) {
    noFill();
    stroke(collidingColor);
    strokeWeight(3);
    rect(x, y, w, h)
}

function moveX(object, speed) {
    object.x += speed;
}

function moveY(object, speed) {
    object.y += speed;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```